# postgresql error on rails precompile prior to push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Working on lessons learning Rails online. 
I run the following commands --

> **set RAILS_ENV=production**
>
> **bundle exec rake assets:precompile**

This is the error I get --

> **rake aborted! ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'postgresql' database is not configured. Avai lable: ["default", "development",
>   "test", "production", "adapter", "database", " encoding",
>   "min_messages", "pool", "timeout"]
>   C:/Users/username/work/stukdo/config/environment.rb:5:in `' Tasks: TOP => environment (See full trace by running task
>   with --trace**

My gemfile has the following:

```
group :development, :test do
gem 'spring'
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'pg'
end
```

...and here's my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
adapter: sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
<<: *default
database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
<<: *default
database: db/test.sqlite3

production: &default
adapter: postgresql
database: todoism
encoding: utf8
min_messages: warning
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

Any ideas? I'm following the lesson exactly. I'm trying to precompile these files before uploading them to heroku.

Comment: Please post your /config/environment.rb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files should look like this:

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

/config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     localhost
  encoding: utf8
  database: todoism
  pool:     5
  username: <%= ENV['PG_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PG_PASSWORD'] %>
  template: template0
  # others options

test:
   adapter:  postgresql
   host:     127.0.0.1
   encoding: utf8
   database: todoism
   pool:     5
   username: <%= ENV['PG_USERNAME'] %>
   password: <%= ENV['PG_PASSWORD'] %>
   template: template0
   # others options

production:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     127.0.0.1
  encoding: utf8
  database: todoism
  pool:     5
  username: <%= ENV['PG_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PG_PASSWORD'] %>
  template: template0
  # others options
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move that last chunk of code in your database.yml file:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: todoism
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: YOUR USERNAME
  password: <%= ENV['THE DATABASE PASSWORD YOU CONFIGURED ON HEROKU'] %>
```